# Mathematical calculation in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm

I wanna write a function using this formula!

> Take a list of ages when each of your great-grandparent died.
>
> Multiply each number by itself.
>
> Add them all together.
>
> Take the square root of the result.
>
> Divide by two.

This is an example:

```
predictAge(65, 60, 75, 55, 60, 63, 64, 45) === 86
```

This is the code I wrote:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
int predictAge(std::vector<int> ages)
{
 for(int i = 0; i < ages.size(); i++) {
   int Produc = ages[i] * ages[i];
   int Sum = Produc + Produc;
   int Squar = sqrt(Sum);
   int Final = Squar / 2;
   std::cout << Final << "\n";  
   
 } 
}
int main() {
  std::cout << predictAge({65, 60, 75, 55, 60, 63, 64, 45});
  return 1;
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: _Can anyone help?_ You don't describe your problem. What help do you need? (Please, [edit] and describe the issue in detail you're stuck on.)

Comment: Looking at your exposed code, you didn't follow your concept (or requirement) beginning from _Add them all together._

Comment: `int Sum = Produc + Produc;` is not how you sum all the values. Hint: define `int Sum = 0;` *before* the loop to make it keep its value between iterations, then modify it inside. Next, `sqrt` and `/2` are supposed to happen after the loop (because you do that with the sum, not with every number). Next, you must decide where to print the result. Either you print it in `predictAge` (then the return type must be `void`, and `std::cout <<` is not needed in `main`), or you print it in `main` (then `predictAge` must `return` the result instead of printing).

Comment: Exactly, Scheff.

Answer (score 4):

Something like:

```cpp
int predictAge(std::vector<int> ages)
{
  int Sum = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < ages.size(); i++) {
    int Produc = ages[i] * ages[i];
    Sum += Produc;  
  }
  return sqrt(Sum) / 2;
}
```

You should take care about input data checking and errors handling.

Answer (score 4):

You spell out the correct algorithm, you simply fail to implement it properly. You want the RSS (root sum square) divided by two of the all ages in your `std::vector`. Since RSS is a common algorithm, why not just write a function to calculate the RSS of all values and then divide the return by two to complete your algorithm.

You can implement that as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

double rss (std::vector<int>& ages)
{
    double sum = 0.;
    
    for (const auto& a : ages)
        sum += a * a;
    
    return sqrt (sum);
}

int main (void) {
    
    std::vector<int> ages { 65, 60, 75, 55, 60, 63, 64, 45 };
    
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(rss(ages) / 2.) << '\n';
}
```

(**note:** since an integer value is wanted, the return divided by two is cast to `int`. You can remove the cast if you want the floating point result)

Above the `for` loop in the function is a [Range-based for loop (since C++11)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for))

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/rss_ages
86
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further question.

Comment: It`s much higher than What I know from C++

Comment: Oh sorry, it's actually very simple. The function parameter `std::vector<int>& ages` simply passes the `std::vector` `ages` from `main()` to the function `rss()` for processing. Then inside `rss()` the loop just loops over each value (the loop variable is `a` (short for ages) which it then multiplies by itself adding the results to `sum`. After the loop the square-root of `sum` is returned. You can rewrite the `for` loop as `for (auto iter = ages.begin(); iter != ages.end(); iter++)` where `iter` will be a pointer to each element. So you would `sum += *iter * *iter;` The rest is the same.